# Can't login via telnet in ddwrt

Tags: command-line, telnet, dd-wrt

I have a Gateworks laguna 2388 router with `dd-wrt` firmware installed in it. It was working fine till i change "http_passwd" nvram attribute.
I wanted to change the web GUI password via `telnet`. So I changed the nvram attribute by using the following commands:

```
nvram set http_passwd=xxxx 
nvram commit
reboot
```

Now I can't able to login via telnet as well as in web GUI. When I try to login via telnet the console says "Login Incorrect" I aslo connected the device using a console cable, but can't able to login. Is there any way to recover the password without flashing the firmware?

Comment: Do you realise that passwords are encrypted? If you entered plain text password it will not work. Maybe you could get to the router through `ssh` if enabled?

Comment: Baf is right you may have hosed yourself if the argument needed to be a hash and you entered the plain text. Also, you should be able to reset your router to default settings to fix this if all else fails.

Comment: @baf In my device, the ssh is disabled, also 30/30/30 reset is not working in my router. I'm currently able to login to u-boot. I'm trying to erase nvram sectors. But it is also not working.